# Python: those variable dont point to the same values. Why?

Tags: python

I thought that if you assign a variable to another list, it's not copied, but it points to the same location. That's why deepcopy() is for. This is not true with Python 2.7: it's copied.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=a
>>> b=b[1:]+b[:1]
>>> b
[2, 3, 1]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> a=(1,2,3)
>>> b=a
>>> b=b[1:]+b[:1]
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
>>> b
(2, 3, 1)
>>>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What doesn't look right to you?

Comment: You are missing the fact that variables are names. The assignment makes the name `b` point to a newly created object resulting from the expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line changes what `b` points to:

```
b=b[1:]+b[:1]
```

List or tuple addition creates a new list or tuple, and the assignment operator makes `b` refer to that new list while leaving `a` referring to the original list or tuple.

Slicing a list or tuple also creates a new object, so that line creates three new objects - one for each slice, and then one for the sum. `b = a + b` would be a simpler example to demonstrate that addition creates a new object.

You will sometimes see `c = b[:]` as a way to shallow copy a list, making use of the fact that slicing creates a new object.

Comment: Even without the addition, the slicing produces a new object

Answer (score 0):

When you do `b=b[1:]+b[:1]` you first create a new object of two `b` slices and then assign b to reference that object. The same is for both `list` and `tuple` cases